# project stopped being gradle project. NOT MIGRATING

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

**This is not a migrated project.**
I've made a small project in android studio 1.0.2 with all the default settings. It was working well until I encountered a weird problem. It recently just fell apart - literally, nothing works and I don't even know what to look at for the issue.

**Background**

I had a strange problem with v21/something.xml where graddle cmplained about syntax error (it was complaining about lack of /. I saw it looks different ten other similar lines and corrected it to look like the others, but something (gradle script creator?) chaged it back to the form with syntax error.

**Problem**

I've found that similar issue is related to wrong sdk version, I've tried changing minSdkVersion to 21 (from 11) and updated gradle to see red marks pretty much everywhere.
THe puzzling thing is, that when I looked into the event log I saw this:

```
12:28:43 AssertionError: Already disposed: Module: 'app': Already disposed: Module: 'app'
12:28:43 All files are up-to-date
12:30:55 Project Sync
         The project 'Yamba' is not a Gradle-based project
         More Information about migrating to Gradle
```

Clearly the project stopped being a grale one - What a Terrible Failure...
In the project tree, the .idea directory is red and everything within it plus local.properties

All .java files have a red mark on them.

When I try to run the project,  it opens edit configuration dialog and there is no module specified.

How can I find the error source, and more importantly how to fix it? I can upload any code you need - just tell me what is relevant here, as there are too many files to put them all and keep it readable.

the build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.asteroth.yamba"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

EDIT:
I've made a new project under the same name, copied all the files over to it and it builds - something caused corruption in the actual project. I'll try to reproduce it

Comment: I've tried the Build-> rebuild project, to no avail - I haven't seen the option clean in Android Studio.

Comment: Should be right under it, otherwise manually delete the binaries from the project folder?

Comment: Tried to delete everything I could find in the build/generated directory and upon make project I got 16:29:48 Frameworks detected: Android framework is detected in the project Configure
16:30:07 All files are up-to-date
When I try to run it, the Edit configuration dialog pops up and under General tab says Error :module not specified

Comment: Hmmm, I'd try a clean copy of the sdk, android studio and delete /.AndroidStudioBeta. Usually solves all weird problems that you aren't causing yourself.

Comment: I have the 1.0.2 version of android studio - I'll try to make a new project and copy the files over. If this doesn't work, I'll reinstall AS. If this doesn't help either and I can't reproduce it - I'll have to move to eclipse. Thanks for advice.